# What are the best FPM Settings, NGINX Server Adjustments, PHP Ini Editor changes & WHM (my.cnf) file tweaks to boost query and page loading speed

Tags: nginx, my.cnf

Facing issue of slow page loading on my VPS even though website is having optimized code.
Can anyone shows PHP-FPM Settings, NGINX Server Adjustments, PHP-Ini Editor Changes & WHM (my.cnf) file commands for mysql server query optimization to get maximum page loading speed and sql database query execution

Tried to change PHP-FPM Settings, NGINX Server, Cpanel (PHP-Ini Editor) & WHM (my.cnf) file commands to get maximum page loading and mysql query execution.